# RDS to EC2 mysql replication

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, mysql-replication, amazon-rds

I would like to create a RDS mysql and to replicate it to an EC2 server so the DB will be local and thus the query time will be faster (the EC2 is a web server).
According to the second paragraph here [Using Replication to Export MySQL 5.6 Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html):

> Replication to an instance of MySQL running external to Amazon RDS is only supported during the time it takes to export a database from a MySQL DB instance. The replication should be terminated when the data has been exported and applications can start accessing the external instance.

I understand it can't or shouldn't be done.
Am I right?
Is there other alternatives?

Also,
I saw this two below questions but the first was the other way and the second was years ago before the RDS replication feature was even available:

1. [Is it possible to use an EC2 RDS MySQL instance as a slave to an external master?](https://serverfault.com/questions/193220/is-it-possible-to-use-an-ec2-rds-mysql-instance-as-a-slave-to-an-external-master)
2. [Amazon RDS to EC2 replication](https://serverfault.com/questions/356536/amazon-rds-to-ec2-replication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand it can't or shouldn't be done. Am I right?

I would say you are incorrect, in spite of the fact that what you are saying seems consistent with what's documented.

A plain reading of the documentation notwithstanding, you can do this indefinitely, on an ongoing basis, as long as you don't expect Amazon to provide support for your non-standard configuration... which, to me, seems reasonable.  Almost certainly, using native replication like this is a better alternative than any other mechanism.

As of this writing, I have had servers configured like this for over a year with no issues.

Going beyond this anecdotal evidence, confirmation of my position can actually be found [in an official RDS Webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6sD28WdYFc), in a conversation that begins at around 56:45:

> "You can keep it in a replicated state indefinitely...
>
> "...as long as you take the responsibility to maintain the replication..."
>
> "We are not preventing you from doing ongoing replication if that's what you want."

Note that, as always with MySQL replication, your slave's configured `@@SERVER_ID` must be different than the master's, and different than any other RDS or non-RDS replica connecting to the same master.

Comment: That is a great answer.
It would be great if you can share your steps to do this kind of replication.